# How to stop program crashing on 19th run?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that draws two random cards but will not draw those two same cards again when new cards are drawn. For some reason, on the 19th run of the program, the window freezes and I have to stop and restart the program. I've noticed that every time new cards are drawn the memory use increases up to 159MBs and then on the 19th draw, it drops back down with a yellow "Indicates start of a managed heap garbage collection" (not sure if this is relevant, I'm relatively new to C# and this is my first GUI program).

Here is the code and 2 bits of info as I know there are no comments

1. Cards are stored in a resource file called Resource1
2. Cards are named "_[number 1-13][suit H, C, D, S]" e.g. "_3C" is 3 of clubs

```c
namespace Card_Dealer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] drawncards = new string[52];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string randomCard()
        {
            bool valid = false;
            string cardc = "";
            int i = 1;
            string convertedcards = "";

            do
            {
                cardc = "_";
                Random random = new Random();
                cardc += random.Next(1, 13);
                int suit = random.Next(1, 4);
                switch (suit)
                {
                    case 1: cardc += "H"; break;
                    case 2: cardc += "C"; break;
                    case 3: cardc += "D"; break;
                    case 4: cardc += "S"; break;
                }
                cardc += "";
                foreach (var x in drawncards.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
                {
                    if (cardc == x.value)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (x.value == null)
                    {
                        valid = true;
                        drawncards[x.index] = cardc;
                        foreach (string el in drawncards) { convertedcards += el + " "; }
                        label1.Text = convertedcards;          
                        return cardc;
                    }
                }
            } while (valid == false);
            return "";        
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawncards.Contains(null))
            {  
                string cardc = randomCard();
                object O = Resource1.ResourceManager.GetObject(cardc);
                card1.Image = (Image)O;
                card1.Image = new Bitmap(card1.Image, new Size(345, 528));

                string cardc2 = randomCard();
                object J = Resource1.ResourceManager.GetObject(cardc2);
                card2.Image = (Image)J;
                card2.Image = new Bitmap(card2.Image, new Size(345, 528));
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text ="All Cards Drawn!";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to stop the program from crashing?

Thanks!

Comment: Dispose of the old images before creating new ones! `if (card1.Image != null) Bitmap dummy = (Bitmap) card1.Image; card1.Image = null; dummy.Dispose();` etc..

Comment: Let me suggest that you debug your own code and inspect its behavior. From your question it's hard even to understand what the 'crash' is. Also, [avoid the repeated instantiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#Multiple) of `Random`.

Comment: @Taw Yes, sorry I forgot to say, I've tried this and it appears to have no effect

Comment: @OndrejTucny Thanks for the advice on `random`, also I have tried to debug the code but I don't understand. By 'crash' I just mean the window freezes and doesn't respond to any clicks.

Comment: You should move random instance creation at class level to avoid same numbers.

Comment: @A.S I have a *theory* regarding the freeze, see my answer. To validate, break the program execution in the IDE and see if it's spinning in the `do` loop.

Comment: Looks like you get stuck inside the do while loop. When it hangs break into it (by pressing the pause button in VS) and inspect your data!

Comment: @TaW He keeps creating a `Random` instance in each iteration of the `do` loop and there will be many iterations for a single mouse click = it **is** a problem.

Comment: Yup just noted it; the real issue is not getting out of the loop though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *likely* reason for your code to freeze is that:

1. you instantiate the `Random` class each and every iteration of the main `do` loop, which increases the probability of producing the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers, thus yielding the *same* card every iteration; and,
2. you approach the problem from the opposite direction than it was architecturally savvy: you randomly generate the *resulting* cards instead of randomly *picking* cards from a stack.

Then, because of (1), the `do` loop keeps generating same cards and in conjunction with (2) it never (or only after some non-trivial number of iterations) finds an undrawn card.

Let me suggest you rewrite your code according to the following:

- have a *single* `Random` instance as a field of the class
- have a `List<string> availableCards` field and in the beginning
- construct drawing cards as removing items from the `availableCards` and placing them to a `List<string> drawnCards`
- use the `Random` instance to generate *indexes* into `availableCards` instead of the cards themselves

---

Further possible improvements:

- use properties instead of fields
- decompose the *business logic* (i.e. management of the card stack, drawing cards) into a separate class, decoupled from the user interface (the form class)
- separate data from logic—having a separate data class to encapsulate a stack of cards and separate business logic class to manage drawing cards

Comment: _you approach the problem from the opposite direction than it was architecturally savvy_ - That is very nicely put :-)

Comment: @TaW Uhmmm could it be said it were *welcoming* and *friendly*? (grin) (tongueincheek)

Comment: Thank you very much @OndrejTucny! The code no longer freezes and is _far_ shorter, though it still has high memory use at 184MB despite @Taw suggestion before but memory use isn't something I'm bothered about for this so it's fine.

Comment: _welcoming and friendly?_ yup, but my main point was that it was analytically helpful.

Comment: @A.S : Now that you are disposing of the bitmaps the GC has a change to collect them __eventually__, that is when memory becomes scarce.

Comment: @TaW Yeah, I understood it, but couldn't resist making a reference to that *w* and *f* things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing your program to crash, I was able to make a class and unit test that does basically the same thing but without the UI components.

The one issue I did find is that you are appending whitespace to your label when iterating through the drawncards array, even when those items are null. You can filter out these null items by modifying your foreach like so
`foreach (string el in drawncards.Where(card => card != null))`

I personally would use a list instead of an array and only add items to the list after the card has been drawn.

Sorry this is not a complete answer, I would have posted as a comment but I don't have rights to do so yet.

EDIT:

I'd also modify the body of the loop so that it doesn't add whitespace between between the label items unless at least one item has already been added:

```
foreach (string el in drawncards.Where(card => card != null))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(convertedcards))
        convertedcards += " ";
    convertedcards += el;
}
```